# SAML-based SSO for Google Apps replacement

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml

We still have an implementation of this running on an old Tomcat java 1.5 box. Its used to sso for our own domain email via google
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation_web#file-and-directory-structure-for-saml-reference-code

I noticed there is a warning that this is old and no longer compatible. Is there an updated how to or sample that we can implement into an Ear file for websphere with java 1.6 ? I haven't been able to find anything yet. Thanks.